# Excel VBA Formatting Chart Series with Vlookup

Tags: excel, charts, vlookup, vba

I am a new VBA user and am trying to format chart series based upon the series name. I want to use vlookup to reference the series name and return a defined MarkerStyle, MarkerForegroundColor, MarkerSize, etc.. I'm wanting to do this as I have a large list of series names that each need a unique marker and I need to make a large number of charts. I have started a code but keep getting the 1004 error: 'Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class':

```
 Sub ChartFormattingVlookup()
    Dim mySeries As Series
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim vbc As Range
    Set vbc = Worksheets("VBAChartFormat").Range("A2:I44")

    For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        cht.Activate
        For Each mySeries In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
            With mySeries
                .MarkerSize = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(mySeries, vbc, 7, False)
                .MarkerStyle = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(mySeries, vbc, 6, False)
            End With
        Next mySeries
    Next cht
End Sub
```

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: the `mySeries` placement in the first argument of vlookup is incorrect. The argument is expecting a range reference or a literal string and you are passing a seriescollection object. If you pass `mySeries.Name` it will work, so long as the lookup table has the series name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following-up on @Scott Holtzman comment why you are getting the error on your `VLookup` function, there is also no need to `Activate` the `cht` and then use `ActiveChart`, just use `For Each mySeries In cht.SeriesCollection`.

Also, you should consider adding error-hanlding to possible failures of `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChartFormattingVlookup()

    Dim mySeries As Series
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim vbc As Range

    Set vbc = Worksheets("VBAChartFormat").Range("A2:I44")

    For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        For Each mySeries In cht.SeriesCollection
            With mySeries
                If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(mySeries.Name, vbc, 7, False)) Then '<-- check VLookup was successfull
                    .MarkerSize = Application.VLookup(mySeries.Name, vbc, 7, False)
                End If
                If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(mySeries.Name, vbc, 6, False)) Then '<-- check VLookup was successfull
                    .MarkerSize = Application.VLookup(mySeries.Name, vbc, 6, False)
                End If
            End With
        Next mySeries
    Next cht

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much for your comments. Scott, what if my series name is not a String but an integer?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You're right it is fine, thanks!